# Download .pdf file from website. File is corrupt

Tags: c#, pdf, webclient

I would like to download the following pdf file (The file is generated within a few seconds after clicking it ):

[PDF Link](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=NL&language=EN-generic&productNumber=271004&brand=SIAL&PageToGoToURL=null)

I tried the following code to do this:

```
static void DownloadByWebClient()
{
    string url = "http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=NL&language=EN-generic&productNumber=271004&brand=SIAL&PageToGoToURL=null";
    string clientfile = @"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\newfile.pdf";

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), clientfile);
}
```

The pdf file is created. However, when I try to open it I get a message that it is corrupt.
Perhaps the problem is that the file is first generated before it can be downloaded?

I've also tried the `DownloadFile` method. But then an error is thrown:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 
Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the  'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied
at System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent.CreateWSASocketWithEvent(AddressFamily addressFamily,
SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, Boolean autoReset, Boolean signaled)
at System.Net.NetworkAddressChangePolled..ctor()
at System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.AutoDetector.Initialize()
at System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.AutoDetector.get_CurrentAutoDetector()
at System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine..ctor(WebProxy proxy, Boolean useRegistry)
at System.Net.WebProxy.UnsafeUpdateFromRegistry()
at System.Net.WebProxy..ctor(Boolean enableAutoproxy)
at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal..ctor(DefaultProxySection section)
at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSection()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSection()
at System.Net.WebRequest.get_InternalDefaultWebProxy()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor(Uri uri, ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create(Uri Uri)
at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

What can be the cause?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think DownloadFile *Async* does?

Comment: Calling async method and immediately disposing? [Please read documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx) especially Remarks first part.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my answer based on the OPs comments and my testing.
I can run the following code and it works just fine. The file is downloaded and the pdf on my local disk is good.

```
public void DLTest()
{
    string url = "https://www.osha.gov/Publications/Abate/abate.pdf";
    string clientfile = @"C:\Test\newfile3.pdf";

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), clientfile);
}
```

However, when I use your url "http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=NL&language=EN-generic&productNumber=271004&brand=SIAL&PageToGoToURL=null" the pdf does not contain data. It appears that the url that you are using does not support downloading of this information as a PDF.

You could try downloading the MSDS from a different site, for example the code below works with a different url.

```
public void DLTest()
{
    string url = "http://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9927335";
    string clientfile = @"C:\Test\newfile.pdf";

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), clientfile);
}
```

Comment: @ Bill W: I've already tried this but then an exception is thrown.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I tried running with DownloadFile(), I don't get an exception, but the downloaded file is corrupt; I will look into this further.

Comment: I Think the problem is that the pdf file is generated based on the articlenumber and displayed when finished. If you click the link you will see that it takes a few seconds untill the pdf is generated. Is there a way to first trigger the generation of the pdf, and download the file after some time (e.g. 30 seconds)?

Comment: Your url does not link to a pdf file. It tells their server to get the info and display it, but you don't have a direct link to a pdf. I don't know how you can get around that.

Comment: I recommend downloading your MSDS from a different site. There are many sources for MSDS, for example, I have updated my answer with a site that does have downloadable links to MSDS.